# Is java hashTable still synchronized in version 7?

Tags: java, collections, synchronization, hashtable

I read one of Oracles tutorial's and it mentioned that hashtable is no longer synchronised. Since when?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html
Third paragraph after the table.

Comment: The link you referred to says "The legacy collections Vector and Hashtable are synchronized".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `Hashtable` is still sychronized. The paragraph you're referring to even says so explicitly:

> *The legacy collections Vector and Hashtable **are synchronized**.*

(The preceeding sentence:

> *[...] The fact that these implementations are unsynchronized [...]*

is referring to the collections in the table which do *not* include `HashTable`.)

Answer (score 4):

The *legacy* class – `Hashtable` – is synchronized.
The *modern* class – `HashMap` – is not synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

From the paragraph you indicated:

> The legacy collections Vector and Hashtable are synchronized.

From the Java 7 Hashtable API reference:

> Unlike the new collection implementations, Hashtable is synchronized.

(see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc: "Unlike the new collection implementations, Hashtable is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use HashMap in place of Hashtable."

So yes HashTable in Java 7 is still fully syncrhonized.